# is it true that $\det(I+A)>0$ , if $\det(A)>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I saw an inequality for $n\times n$ matrices. I was wondering if the inequality is true or not?

Does $\det(A)>0$  imply $\det(I+A)>0$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider $-I$ in $M_n(\Bbb R)$ for an even $n$.

Comment: @Javier: it depends on whether you think $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & \,0 \\ \,0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is simpler or the same

Comment: @Henry: Well, for $n=2$ this this $-I$...

Answer (score 8):

Let $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/2 \end{bmatrix}.$$